# How to fix a particular group "Group B" from res.groups in Odoov8

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

I have a many2one field from res.s. And for this fields i created three groups Group A, Group B and Group C. For these groups i applied on-change for users related to group. And on-change work well. Now, i want that Group B is default group selected. So, How to fix Group B default on form(group id = 33) ?

**My python code:**

```
'group_id':fields.many2one('res.groups', string='Group:')

'assign_to': fields.many2one('res.users','Assigned To:',)


def onchange_assign(self, cr, uid, ids, group_id, context=None):

        if not context:

            context = {}

        res = {}

        groups_obj = self.pool.get('res.groups')

        sunarc_obj = self.pool.get('sun.helpdesk')

        #record_id = context.get('active_id')

        print "g:", group_id

        #data = sunarc_obj.read(cr, uid, record_id)

        #print data

        #group_id = data['group_id'] and data['group_id'][0]

        groups_ids = []

        groups = groups_obj.browse(cr, uid, group_id, context=context)

        print "groups:", groups, groups.users.ids

        if group_id:

            res['domain'] = {'assign_to': [('id', '=', groups.users.ids)]}

        print "group_id"

        return res
```

**XML Code:-**

```
<field name="group_id" on_change="onchange_assign(group_id)"/>                        

<field name="assign_to" options="{'create':false}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to name your group name you can try this method:

```
 def _get_default_esc(self):
    esc_to = self.env['res.groups'].search([('name', '=', 'Group A')], limit=1)
    print "group:"
    return esc_to
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
def _get_default_esc(self):

print "yes:", 33

return 33

    'group_id' : fields.many2one('res.groups', "Group", change_default=True, default=_get_default_esc),
```

Comment: Yes, It's work form me. But, Can you tell me how to done this with search method.